# how to reference database and table from parameter values in SQL procedure?

Tags: sql

I have a stored SQL procedure that I'm running from C#. In C#, I'm doing some logic to determine which database and table to use in the procedure and then passing them in as parameters. So I want my SQL code to be something like this:

```
create procedure MyProc
  @database varchar(100),
  @table varchar(100)
as
begin
  insert into [@database].dbo.[@table]
  values (...)
end
```

I'm pretty sure that ain't gonna work though, and when I search for how to do this I get a whole lot of results for stuff I'm not trying to do. Anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: You are going to want to use dynamic SQL probably. (You'll also need to watch for SQL injection). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, EdmCoff. Yeah I ended up being able to use dynamic SQL. I'm surprised there isn't a better way to do it though, unless there is and I just never could find it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't for the general case. But if you have a limited number of possibilities, you could use `if...else` blocks (with a different insert statement in each).